# Wix - WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder vs WixBundleSourceProcessFolder

Tags: wix, burn

The documentation for the WiX built-in variables is [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html).

`WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder - gets the folder from where the bundle originally ran.`

`WixBundleSourceProcessFolder - gets the source folder of the bundle where originally executed. Will only be set when bundle is executing in the clean room`

Two questions:

- What is the difference between "ran" and "executed"?
- What does it mean (and what are the ramifications) of "Will only be set when bundle is executing in the clean room"?

I'm coming across an issue where the product has already been installed. In which case, `WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder` is not what I want. I want the folder where the user has just double clicked on the setup.exe, which may be different to the original folder. `WixBundleSourceProcessFolder` seems to give me the right folder but the description of it makes me a bit nervous and I wanted some clarification on what it really means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tighten up slightly on the answer that Sharpenologist gave:

`WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder` is where the software was *originally* run from. So if you downloaded something and ran it from your downloads folder, that's what it will return. WiX remembers this location for all subsequent runs, even if you've now deleted that folder (or removed it, if it was, say, a DVD or USB key). So on uninstall, this folder will be the place that you originally run the install from, whether it exists or not.

`WixBundleSourceProcessFolder` is where the software is *currently* being run from. So this might be the same as `WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder` on first run, but will come from the package cache on a repair or a uninstall. It'll also come from the package cache if you need a reboot during installation.

Is that any clearer?

Answer (score 2):

In this context, 'ran' means where the bundle executable was located when it was double-clicked [or run from a command line] ... and 'executed' means the location where a copy of the bundle executable was actually run by the system after it was invoked.

Clear as mud?